# Validate @Param in NestJS

Tags: javascript, validation, nestjs

How can I validate path variable in NestJS, like:

```
update(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() updateSite: UpdateSiteDto) {
      // ...body
}
```

I just want to validate `id` is positive(> 0) without wrap class.

Comment: Using DTO we can validate the path params also

Comment: Thank your answer @BennisonJ. Your mean is create a wrap class like DTO to validate?

Comment: What kind of validation you would like to add is it for type validation or not?

Answer (score 3):

This is a useful question.

I use a custom pipe to validate the `id` param

Step 1: Create `pipe.ts` file:

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class PositiveNumberValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  async transform(value: number) {
    if (value <= 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException('id is positive number');
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Step 2: use it in Controller file by import file `pipe.ts`

```
@Post('/users/:id')
update(
    @Param('id', PositiveNumberValidationPipe) id: number,
    @Body() updateSite: UpdateSiteDto,
) {
    // ...body
}
```

If you send non-positive number, you receive the result:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "id is positive number",
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

It worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check id in the body below

```
 update(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() updateSite: UpdateSiteDto) {
   if (id < 1) {
     throw new BadRequestException('ID_MUST_BE_POSITIVE');
   }
   // ...body
 }
```